# How to write sql to convert one string from mutiple rows?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Supose I have a table with following kind of data:

```
Tab(id, myString)
1  A
2  B
3  C
...
```

I want to a SQL can return all one string for all values in  Column myString. So the result I want looks like:  "A, B, C"

If I don't want to use cursor and stored procedure, is it possible sql to get such kind of result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Declare @tbl table(ID nvarchar(1),[myString] nvarchar(100))
Insert into @tbl values(1,'A'); 
Insert into @tbl values(2,'B'); 
Insert into @tbl values(3,'C'); 
DECLARE @CSVList varchar(100)

SELECT @CSVList = COALESCE(@CSVList + ' , ', '') + 
   [myString]
FROM @tbl


SELECT @CSVList
```

Answer (score 2):

Use T-SQL row concatenation:

```
declare @s varchar(max)
set @s = ''
select @s = @s +
 case when @s = '' then '' else ', ' end + Letter
from MyTable

select @s
```

**edited** removed trailing ", "

Answer (score 2):

A combination of using [FOR XML PATH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) (providing an empty element name) and [STUFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) is a common SQL Server (2005+) technique. It doesn't require declaration of any local variables and can therefore be run outside of batch or procedure.

```
SELECT STUFF(
(SELECT ',' + t.myString
FROM TAB t
ORDER BY t.Id
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS CSV
```